# How do I change the theme of the Arduino IDE?

Tags: 12.04, arduino

The `theme.txt` file is said to be somewhere in the the `themes` folder, which itself has to be in the Arduino folder in `/lib` or `/usr/lib`, but I cant find either of the files.

Where are the files located ?

Is there any other way to change the theme ?

*theme=color-scheme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `sudo updatedb` then `locate arduino` or `locate theme.txt` or a related search.

On my system, I see `theme.txt` in the installation directory:

`./arduino-1.0.3/lib/theme/theme.txt`

A related issue is discussed on [this blog](http://blog.markloiseau.com/2012/05/install-arduino-ubuntu/) :

> To make Arduino use the native Swing windowing instead of forcing the
>   GTK look and feel [...] change the following line:

```
#comment out this line:
#java -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel processing.app.Base

#change it to this:
java processing.app.Base
```

If this is still relevant, you might be able to work with themes by changing GTK theming directly.